# C#, Wix toolset. Why does deleting and updating delete a file that was created by my application?

Tags: c#, wpf, wix

I have a WPF application, to create an installer, I chose the Wix toolset. My application creates a local database, it is not included in the lists of files for installation. When I uninstall the app, my DB file is deleted, this works, but when I update an application, the file is also deleted. Help me figure out how to ensure that the file is not deleted during the update, but is deleted when the application is only deleted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <?define ProductName="MyApp"?>
    <?define TargetFileName="MyApp Desktop.exe"?>
    <?define description="MyApp"?>

    <Product Id="*" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Language="1033" Version="1.0.8.0" Manufacturer="$(var.ProductName)" UpgradeCode="e7fa5ab6-bed7-4850-97e2-270bfd182983">

        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Description="$(var.description)"/>

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed."/>
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Installer" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="ShortcutMenu" />
            <ComponentRef Id="ShortcutDesktop" />
            <ComponentRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER_Permission" />
            <ComponentRef Id="MyAppFolder" />
        </Feature>

        <Icon Id="icon" SourceFile="IconApp.ico"/>
        <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon" />

        <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="Images/TopBanner.png"/>
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="Images/DialogBanner.png"/>

        <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" ></Property>

        <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>

        <Feature Id="BlazorAppFeature"
                 Title="BlazorWasmApplication"
                 Level="1"
                 ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
                 AllowAdvertise="no"
                 Absent='disallow'>
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="PublishedComponents" />
        </Feature>

    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="StructureIT">
            
                    <Component Id="MyAppFolder" Guid="24f047db-b522-478e-b0aa-fcc552c2f1a2">
                        <RemoveFile Id="PurgeAppFolder" Name="MyAppDB.db" On="uninstall" />
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="decktop"/>

            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="MenuFolder" >
                <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="Structure IT" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <Component Id="ShortcutMenu" Guid="302df662-167e-42b7-94ae-cb2ab4dec1a6"  Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
            <Shortcut Id="StartMenu" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Description="$(var.description)" Target ="[INSTALLFOLDER]$(var.TargetFileName)" />
            <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveShortcut"  On="uninstall"/>
            <Registry Root="HKCU" Key="SoftWare\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <Component Id="ShortcutDesktop" Guid="e6a03b11-01b2-45ba-b7b3-77b0c09cdd3d" Directory="DesktopFolder" >
            <Shortcut Id="ShortcutDesktop" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Description="$(var.description)" Target ="[INSTALLFOLDER]$(var.TargetFileName)" />
            <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveDesktopFolder" Directory="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall" />
            <Registry Root="HKCU" Key="SoftWare\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="INSTALLFOLDER_Permission" Guid="76f2583f-d81a-4ea7-a76a-0eb08732b3e0">
                <CreateFolder>
                    <util:PermissionEx User="Users" GenericAll="yes"/>
                </CreateFolder>
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

The RemoveFile On="Uninstall" doesn't mean uninstall of the application it means uninstall of the component.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/removefile-table

Because your doing a major upgrade you're essentially uninstalling and reinstalling the component thus the file is deleted.

There's a few ways to address this.

1. If you have an EXE bootstrapper, place the component in it's own MSI and never update the MSI.  This way the bootstrapper never updates that MSI and it only gets installed once and removed once.
2. Change the scheduling of RemoveExistingProducts in the Major Upgrade so that components get installed first and then removed. In this way the component won't be removed until final uninstall.  This has side effects though that have to be understood.
3. Use a custom action with a condition of REMOVE="ALL" and Not UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE to delete the file.

Or altenatively don't delete the file at all.  Microsoft guidelines do actually say you shouldn't remove user data.